# How to enable drag/relocate of my FF toolbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

When I go into Customize Toolbar, I can drag other toolbars to different position.

When I install **my extension** it positions on top-left, and I can't drag it from there. The mouse doesn't change into draggable grab/hand.

What did I missed in the configuration? How can I enable users to be able to drag my toolbar to different position?

**Note: I am developing the toolbar, so it's not a superuser question.**

Comment: i don't believe this belongs here....

Comment: I am developing my toolbar and I can't enable this feature for my toolbar. I think I miss something in XUL or in configuration, like my items have no draggable status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can drag your `<toolbar>`. You can drag items on the `<toolbar>`; to do this they need to live on the `<toolbarpalette>` (you can set the `defaultset` attribute to make them appear on your `<toolbar>` by default), or in newer versions of Firefox you can set the `removable="true"` attribute on the items.